# How to populate a ListAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

What is the best way to load a list adapter.  Simple question but I already know what most of you are going to say.  You are going to say use the LoaderManager / CursorManager.  Everyone is going to tell me how easy it is to use and that it doesn't do work on the UI thread (which I understand why that is important).  Here is my issue.  My app is fairly simple and I don't want to create a ContentProvider (which seems to  be necessary with using the CursorManager).  I am using a SQLLite database.  What are some other methods that I can use to populate a ListAdapter?  What are the PROS/CONS?  Am I too believe that Android/Google wants all database connections to be made via a ContentProvider?  If not what are some other acceptable ways of accessing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy the source code of `CursorLoader` and simply change how it does the query for the Cursor. Instead of getting a `ContentResolver` and using a URI, have it query a `SQLiteDatabase` that you supply (perhaps through the constructor). Then you can use this loader instead of the standard `CursorLoader`.

I may take a stab at this, but in the meantime, [here is the source for `CursorLoader`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/CursorLoader.java).

Comment: I actually found some sample code on GitHub by ultimate-deej does exactly as you suggested.  Thanks for the information.  One last question shouldn't Android have already provided a class that does just that.  Why would they force people to use ContentProviders to access data.